# Display two labels for each bar in highcharts(one inside and one outside)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I wanted to display two labels on bars. I am able to display one label right now. I want something like this.

[image]

Instead I am getting like this[image]

The code snippet which I am using to show the labels is

```
plotOptions: {

                            column: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: "black",
                                    style: {
                                        textOutline: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

how Can I show these percentage value on the bars? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

For placing label with percentage inside the particular column you should give `dataLabels` inside that series, for rest of the column use common `dataLabels` as defined by you in `plotOptions`. Below code is for idea only [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/7dbg161b/6/)

```
var data = [7, 12, 16, 32];
var dataSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  dataSum += data[i]
}
var data2 = [5, 19, 14, 13];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {

    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: "black",
        style: {
          textOutline: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'first',
    data: data,
    dataLabels: {
      y: 20, /*for placeing lables values inside column*/
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y , 0) +'<br>'+Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Second',
    data: data2,
  }]
});
```

Comment: You can use "inside: true" in dataLabels to have them inside the column area.